# Openlayers 3 - Create symbol like openlayers 2 -> OpenLayers.Renderer.symbol.anySymbol

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2, maps

In the `Openlayers v2` I could add symbols like:

```
OpenLayers.Renderer.symbol.pointToIcon = [100, 70, 20, 50, 42, 70, 20, 90];
```

How can I do it with Openlayers 3 ?

In the `openlayers 3` I can use this feature:

```
var starSymbol = new ol.style.RegularShape({
    points: 4,
    opacity: .5,
    radius: 10,
    radius2: 10 * .5,
    angle: 130,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "blue"
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "red",
        width: 1
    })
});
```

I can make the other figures,but I can't make the following figure.

[image]

In addition, I don't use 'Icon' like:

```
new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: 'data/icon.png'
    }))
})
```

Because the color of icon is fixed and I can't use my needed colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378461/openlayers-3-create-symbol-like-openlayers-2-openlayers-renderer-symbol-any/34416569#34416569). We can use [earthquake custom symbol](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/earthquake-custom-symbol.html) to create own custom shapes.